# Can Edge browser open SharePoint files directly into "Client Application"?

Tags: sharepoint-server, edge

Like IE does ?

In Edge it works by pointing to the file and then three dots then choose "Open in Word" , which works - but how to change it to do this on clicking the file itself ?

Answer (score 0):

In library settings-> Advanced settings, choose Open in the client application for Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents.

[image]